# Why is matrix addition not working in this code?

Tags: java, arrays, function, matrix, methods

Can anyone tell me why matrix addition is not working in this code? All other parts of the program are working except the addition part. It's just printing an empty array as output.

```java
import java.util.*;

class matrix{
    int n1, n2 = 0;
    int[][] matrix1 = new int [n1][n2];
    int[][] matrix2 = new int [n1][n2];
    int[][] matrix3 = new int [n1][n2];
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     
    // get the dimensions of the matrix//
    void Matrix() {
        int n1, n2 = 0;
        System.out.println(" enter the dimension of the matrix");
        n1 = sc.nextInt();
        n2 = sc.nextInt();
        int[][] matrix1 = new int [n1][n2];
        int[][] matrix2 = new int [n1][n2]; 
    
     
        //get the values of the elements//
        System.out.println("Enter the elements of the matrix");
        for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
                matrix1[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
                matrix2[i][j] = matrix1[i][j];
            }
        }
        // print the arrays
        System.out.println("matrix1"+Arrays.deepToString(matrix1));
        System.out.println("matrix2"+Arrays.deepToString(matrix2));
    }

    void add() {
        int[][] matrix3 = new int[n1][n2];
        for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j < n2; j++) {
                matrix3[i][j] = matrix1[i][j] + matrix2[i][j];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Addition of the elements" + Arrays.deepToString(matrix3));
    }
}
```

```java
public class arrays2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        matrix M1 = new matrix();
        M1.Matrix();
        M1.add();   
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you have local matrices `matrix1`, `matrix2` in the scope of method `Matrix()`.  You do not need to redeclare them inside the method, just assign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to redeclare instance variables `n1`, `n2`, `matrix1`, `matrix2` inside method `Matrix()` if you are going to use them in other method:

```java
// get the dimensions of the matrix//
    void Matrix() {
        System.out.println(" enter the dimension of the matrix");
        this.n1 = sc.nextInt();
        this.n2 = sc.nextInt();
        this.matrix1 = new int [n1][n2];
        this.matrix2 = new int [n1][n2]; 
     
        //get the values of the elements//
        System.out.println("Enter the elements of the matrix");
        for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
                matrix1[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
                matrix2[i][j] = matrix1[i][j];
            }
        }
        // print the arrays
        System.out.println("matrix1"+Arrays.deepToString(matrix1));
        System.out.println("matrix2"+Arrays.deepToString(matrix2));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You already declared `n1`, `n2`, `matrix1` and `matrix2` at the beginning of your class, so you shouldn't redeclare them inside your method `Matrix()` because they'll be considered as local variables.

Your code should be something like This :

```
void Matrix() {
n1 = 0;
n2 = 0;
System.out.println(" enter the dimension of the matrix");
n1=sc.nextInt();
n2=sc.nextInt();
matrix1= new int [n1][n2];
matrix2= new int [n1][n2];
...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter the size of row:-");
    int r=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("enter the column of array:-");
    int c=sc.nextInt();
    int[][] arr1=new int[r][c];
    int[][] arr2=new int[r][c];
    int[][] arr3=new int[r][c];
    int i,j,k,l,m,n;
    System.out.println("first matrix:- ");
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            arr1[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
        }
    }System.out.println("second matrix:");
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            arr2[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
        }
    }System.out.println("third matrix:- ");
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            arr3[i][j]=arr1[i][j]+arr2[i][j];
        }
    }System.out.println("adding is:- ");
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            System.out.println(arr3[i][j]+" ");
        }
    }System.out.println("\n");
    
}
```

}